# What's the name of this category

Tags: category-theory

We can usually build new categories from old ones, as example we have the slice $\mathfrak C/A$ and coslice categories $A/\mathfrak C$ of $\mathfrak C$ with an object $A$. I'm reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821847813) and I'm looking for the name of this new from the category $\mathfrak C$ with its standard symbol:

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it isomorphic to the category $C_{A\times B}$?

Comment: @AlexNelson What I know $A\times B$ is the final object of $C_{A,B}$

Comment: @AlexNelson but my goal is know if this kind of category has a special name as slice and coslice categories.

Comment: @AlexNelson and know if the $C_{A,B}$ is indeed the standard symbol of this kind of category.

Answer (score 5):

It is the category of cones over the diagram $\{0,1\} \to \mathsf C : 0 \mapsto A, 1 \mapsto B$. I don't think there is a standard notation for it.

Comment: if you call your functor $F$, then this category is called $Cone(F)$. You can find this notation in Awodey , for example.

Comment: Is there any special name to this category?